# Polynomial ring homomorphism and group ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose that $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$. I want to show that $R[X]/(X^n-1)\cong R(G)$ where $R(G)$ is a group ring.

Could you give me an idea about it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is an $R$-algebra, we have natural bijections
$$\hom_{\mathsf{Alg}(R)}(R[G],A) \cong \hom_{\mathsf{Grp}}(G,A^*) \cong \{a \in A : a^n=1\} \cong \hom_{\mathsf{Alg}(R)}(R[X]/(X^n-1),A),$$
hence, $R[G] \cong R[X]/(X^n-1)$ by Yoneda. If $G=\langle \sigma \rangle$, the isomorphism maps $\sum_i r_i \sigma^i$ to $\sum_i r_i X^i$. If you don't like universal properties and instead have fun with calculating things, you can also check directly that this defines an isomorphism.

The same proof shows: If
$$G = \langle g_1,\dotsc,g_n : R_1(g_1,\dotsc,g_n)=\dotsc=R_p(g_1,\dotsc,g_n)=1 \rangle$$
is a group presentation, then we get an algebra presentation
$$R[G] \cong R \langle X_1^{\pm 1},\dotsc,X_n^{\pm 1} : R_1(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)=\dotsc=R_p(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)=1 \rangle.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ is a generator of $G,$ the morphism
$$R[X]\to R[G],\quad P(X)\mapsto P(g)$$
is onto, and its kernel is $(X^n-1).$